# why div position does not set properly

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

[image: This is my HTML output look like]

Box bordered in  **Red** is my **Droppable** div area. which is having image set as background

Box bordered in **Blue** is my **Draggable** div Area which contains **pointer pin image** which can be dropped to **droppable** region

one of **Dropped pointer** is shown by **Black Arrow**

*Here is code*

```
<body>
<div id="Droppable" class="ui-ui-corner-all">
    Drop Area</div>
<div id="Draggable" class="ui-ui-corner-all">
    <img class="draggableItem" id="Item1" src="Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    <div class="draggableItem" id="Item2">
        <img src="Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="draggableItem" id="Item3">
        <img src="Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="draggableItem" id="Item4">
        <img src="Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="draggableItem" id="Item5">
        <img src="Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="draggableItem" id="Item6">
        <img src="Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve following functionality.

1) User can drop Pointer pin on Droppable region.

2) Once a Pointer pin is dropped on Droppable region I will read Pointer pin's Left Top position using **jQuery** function .**position**

3) Then those **Left** and **Top** Value **I am storing in Database** by making **jQuery ajax** call.

4) Then another page get all pointer position from the DB and show those pointer on the same image where the Pointer were dropped.

**Issue Facing**

When I read all **pointer position from the Database and show those pointer** on the image with respective Left Top position

Pointer is not get placed where it was dropped

**Now the code for both page are same means I render pointer position on the same page where it was dropped.**

its showing as following Image

[image]

Javscript code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".draggableItem").draggable();


        $("#Droppable").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                //my business logic
                 var droppablesPos = //Read dropped item postion using  jQuery .position()


              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Feature/SavePointer",
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true,
                data: { "Left": droppablesPos.Left, "Top": droppablesPos.Top},
                success: function (result) {
                    //return message to user

                },
                error: function (req, status, error) { }
            }
            }

        });

    });
```

**Code is very complex I am posting sample to get and Idea**

Here is all code **javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".draggableItem").draggable();
    var droppablesPos = $("#Droppable").position();
    var dr = $("#Droppable").offset();

    alert("pos Left:" + droppablesPos.left + " " + "Top:" + droppablesPos.top);
    alert(" offest Left:" + dr.left + " " + "Top:" + dr.top);
    $("#Droppable").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $("#" + ui.draggable.attr("id").toString() + "").addClass("droppedItemClickable");


        }

    });

    $(".draggableItem").click(function () {
        var titleName = $(this).attr("id");
        var droppedItemPosition = $(this).offset();
        if ($(this).is(".droppedItemClickable")) {
            $("#dailog").dialog({ width: 480, height: 400, title: titleName });
            $("#FeatureId").val(titleName);
            $("#FeatureTopPosition").val(droppedItemPosition.top);
            $("#FeatureLeftPosition").val(droppedItemPosition.left);
        }
    });

    $("#featureSubmit").click(function () {
        var FeatureId = "1";
        var FeatureName = $("#featureName").val();
        var FeatureDescription = $("#featureDescription").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Builder/SaveFeature",
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: { "featureId": FeatureId, "featureName": FeatureName, "featureDescription": FeatureDescription },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);

                $(control).val(result.toString());
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) { }
        }
        );
        alert("Feature Submited Successfully...");
        $("#dailog").dialog("close");
    });

    $("#featureCancel").click(function () {
        $("#dailog").dialog("close");
    });
    function ret()
    { return false; }

});
```

and **HTML**

```
 <div id="Droppable" class="ui-ui-corner-all">
    Drop Area</div>

<div id="Draggable" class="ui-ui-corner-all">
    <img class="draggableItem" id="Item1" src="../../Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    <div class="draggableItem" id="Item2">
        <img src="../../Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="draggableItem" id="Item3">
        <img src="../../Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="draggableItem" id="Item4">
        <img src="../../Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="draggableItem" id="Item5">
        <img src="../../Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="draggableItem" id="Item6">
        <img src="../../Images/pointer.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>

<br />
<div id="dailog" class="hidden">
    <form method="post" action="/Builder/UploadFeature" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FeatureId) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.FeatureId)%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FeatureId)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FeatureName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.FeatureName) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FeatureName) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FeatureDesc) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.FeatureDesc) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FeatureDesc) %>
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="ImageUploaded" />
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FeatureLeftPosition)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.FeatureLeftPosition)%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FeatureLeftPosition)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FeatureTopPosition)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.FeatureTopPosition)%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FeatureTopPosition)%>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" onclick="ret()" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: ... from the looks of it, I'd say you're mixing x/y-coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, I'll agree with @Yoshi. If that's not the problem, then we need to see your code.

Comment: @Yoshi you should make this an answer since it looks like this is indeed the issue

Comment: @Keith.Abramo I'm not sure, without seeing any of his code, I feel my assumption is too vague as an answer.

Comment: @Sparky672 i think javascript is not need to add here as its working fine giving pointer Left and Top position. and same value when i set as position to pointer its showing another position

Comment: @Yoshi x/y coordinate I did not get what you want to say. could please explain me ?

Comment: @pramodchoudhari I mean, it looks like you're flipping the top/left position either while saving or restoring the positions.

Comment: Everything here is controlled by jQuery/JavaScript and you don't think it's relevant to post any code??  -1

Comment: @Yoshi I checked out flipping but there is not flippling of the values. value are set properly

Comment: @pramodchoudhari then you'll have to show some code. Probably no one here, is able to guess the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not get the position starting at the code which you did nothing. The draggable position is retrieved **inside** the drop event:

```
 options.drop = function (event, ui) {
      // ui here refers to the element being dropped
      var leftPosition = ui.offset.left;
      var topPosition = ui.offset.top;
 }
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very "unusual" code. But from the first (and second) look I got the impression that you did not actually move the draggable physically to the droppable. So its DOM context is still its old container, just the x/y coordinates changed.

So when you extract those coordinates they will be relative to the position of its original container rather than relative to the droppable container. So if you load the pointer into the droppable with those position coordinates, they will be off.